# What does an EXUP servo and subsequently EXUP eliminator plug actually do?

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha

This question relates to my 2012 Yamaha R6.

I removed the kickstand safety actuator because it was bugging me, I found it useless, and my habit is often to lift the kickstand when I start moving which I was prevented from doing by this device.  So when I removed it I traced the cable all the way to its next connection, pulled out the actuator plus the entire length of now useless cable which was about 4 ft long and just soldered the pins together because I like to keep things clean and leaving that useless cable in place would have irritated my obsessive compulsive personality.  Lol

I'm now about to replace my exup servo with a [graves exup eliminator plug](http://www.gravesport.com/Graves-Motorsports-Yamaha-Exup-Servo-Eliminator.html) and am wondering if it's the same sort of thing.. Just making the connection. I wonder if rather than using the plug if I can just pull the whole cable out and solder the pins like I did with the other thing.

[image: EXUP Servo]

If all the plug is doing is creating a connection to fake the exup servo then I don't really need it and can do the same thing with solder. But if there is any sort of circuitry in the plug then I probably need it. I am not prepared to disassemble this plug I just spent $60 on to find out tho. :/

[image: EXUP Servo Eliminator]

Comment: Keep in mind that there is a myth going round that disabling your EXUP(SET valve on suzuki's) will increase power. This is not true. It will result into power loss. The EXUP valve on the bikes is placed to make back pressure to increase power at low torque. At higer RPM's the EXUP valve is always open and is not blocking the exhause gasses.

Answer (score 1):

The EXUP servo is responsible for closing a valve in your exhaust to create a known amount of backpressure in the exhaust system to allow the engine to work in the way it was designed.

If you have swapped your exhaust then chances are you have already eliminated the EXUP servo.  You can create one, a quick google search reveals you only need a capacitor or two and a few resistors to stop the engine check light illuminating.  Not using the kit and just soldering the pins together could cause your check engine light to illuminate or damage to your ECU if you wire a 12v feed into a 5v line.

Comment: EXUP = EXhaust Upstream Pressure?